# If a variable is coded as yes/no/unknown, is it categorical or ordinal?

Tags: r, categorical-data, ordinal-data

The dataset has ten variables, and I am trying to conduct a cluster analysis. The ten variables are coded yes, no, or unknown. And I converted the character values ('yes', 'no', 'unknown') to numeric values ('1', '0', '(blank)').

1. If the variable is coded in 'yes', 'no', or 'unknown', can I leave the 'unknown' value as blank or do I need to re-code the values to 1, 2, and 3 in ordinal way? (e.g., 3 = yes, 2 = no, 1 = unknown)
2. If the variable is coded in 'yes', 'no', or 'unknown', do I need to set the variable as categorical (using `as.factor`) or as ordinal (using `as.ordinal`)?
3. If the total proportion of 'unknown' is about 60% in my dataset, would it be appropriate to conduct the cluster analysis?

I first coded the values in 1 = yes, 0 = no, blank = unknown. And I used 'EGAnet' package to conduct the cluster analysis. And I tried two ways. One is setting the variables as categorical variable with 2-level. Another one is replacing the missing ('unknown) values using this code:

```r
data <- replace(data, is.na(data), "")
```

and setting the variables as ordinal variable (3-level: "" < 0 < 1).

Finally, I run the EGAnet `EGAglasso <- EGA(data = data, model = "glasso")` to see the clusters and correlations among the variables.
However, I got different results depending on whether I set the variables as categorical or ordinal.

Comment: re: your question - ordinal data is data that has an order - an example would be very bad, bad, good, very good. Unknown doesn't have a place within the order within yes or no. You could potentially use TRUE, FALSE, and NA, if you don't know, but maybe you want to reserve NA for missing data (as opposed to things you know you don't know)

Comment: @Mark yes and no already doesn't have an order.

Comment: @Roland fair! In so far that two items order is kinda irrelevant, and they don't have a meaningful order ‍♂️ brain fade my apologies

Comment: Thank you so much, @Roland! I understand your comments. Then it would be appropriate to set the variables as categorical with two levels. One of my concern is about 60% of data are coded as unknown so I think there are too many missing data..

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Mark! I understand that 'unknown' does not have a place. The problem is I have too many unknown values in my dataset :(

Comment: @user21531215 do you have any NAs in your dataset?

Comment: for the statistical stuff, you're much better off asking on Cross Validated

Comment: It can be a valid aproach to model "unknown" as a separate category. Important questions are why are they unknown and if you only have one type of unknown. It looks like you have data from a survey and you should read some literatur regarding how to analyze such data or talk to an expert.

Comment: @Mark if the 'unknown' values are coded NA, they will be the missing values.

Comment: I mean outside of those

Comment: @Roland thank you for your advise. I will try to figure out the solutions!

Comment: @Mark No, there is no other NAs in the dataset.

Comment: in that case, you could turn the column into a logical, with yes = TRUE, no = FALSE, unknown = NA. But I'd check on Cross Validated about the statistical stuff first because that's not my area of expertise

Comment: Define unknown, is it really missing data or does it mean indecisive or no opinion or does the one refuted to answer any question (thinking of a survey). It makes a big difference and if it has a meaning (other than truly missing) it gives value in your analysis and should be treated as a third category. For example, are young people more likely not to answer my question... etc.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/623151/69508

Comment: @Mark it can work very poorly to put 'unknown' as a separate category.  It completely changes the meaning of the variable and can sometimes steal information from Y.  See 
 [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/missing.html#problems-with-simple-alternatives-to-imputation).  This is much more of a place for multiple imputation of the 'unknowns'.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks for sharing! I'll give it a read 

Answer (score 14):

This cannot be answered without knowing exactly what 'unknown' means in your dataset.

If 'unknown' refers to missing data, then it's likely best to replace them with 'NA' and analyse the variables as categorical (i.e. *nominal*, see Nick Cox's comment below).

But imagine that yes/no/unknown were the answers to a question about preference of object A vs. object B. In this case, 'unknown' could mean 'no preference' and if so, there would be a clear sequence: yes > unknown > no. The reverse (no > unknown > yes) is equivalent; the point is that 'unknown' is in the middle. In this situation, it would be reasonable to treat the variables as ordinal.

I would say the first case is more likely but you would know your data better than us.

EDIT: I won't recapitulate them here, but do see the excellent comments below for valuable additional points and caveats.

Comment: Some extra points: Sometimes unknown values are just missing values and reluctantly best left out of analyses; the opposite strategy is to use some kind of imputation to try replacing unknown with either Yes or No. More positively Yes and No can be coded as 1 or 0 and treated quantitatively: Means make sense.  Modelling in terms of probability (logit, probit, etc.) can make sense if Yes/No encodes an outcome. Using the variable as an indicator or dummy predictor can make sense. Such 0, 1 variables can be called binary, dichotomous, Boolean, logical, quantal and likely other names too.

Comment: Readers watch out: _categorical_ narrow sense means (roughly) nominal scale in a widely used if problematic terminology, while _categorical_ wide sense includes ordinal as well. In my reading the wide sense is more common; your reading may differ.

Comment: Thus I disagree with the definition and advice at the tag `categorical`. See for example Agresti's books which use the wider meaning. If you want categorical to mean nominal, why not just say nominal?

Comment: (+1). Just build on your example (and nitpick a bit), it may be difficult to interpret the meaning of "unknown" if it's really an option a respondent can pick. It could mean that the respondent doesn't have an experience of A or B (so she cannot really answer), or that she prefers A but only in specific circumstances, or that she doesn't want us to know her real preference because it's a sensitive topic, etc. So it might be tricky to draw conclusions from it. But I agree with the substance of your answer, in particular as you mention it's important to know what "unknown" means exactly.

Comment: Thanks, excellent points. @NickCox I have to say that I find the terminology around data types frustratingly non-standard and opaque ('interval' and 'nominal' are rather unintuitive to me, for example). I personally find the narrow sense of categorical to be a more useful definition but I mainly wish we had one agreed-upon standard.

Comment: _nominal_ just means that categories have distinct labels or names, but that is the only information. _interval_ means that intervals can be compared but any zero point is arbitrary so ratios don't make sense. Yet the difference between interval and ratio only bites for procedures based on ratios, which means only sometimes.  On the whole (prejudices coming up fast) the scheme nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio is oversold in many people's views and even dangerous if tied up with outdated or dubious dogma about what you must/must not or should/should not do.

Comment: I disagree with the assumption that `yes > unknown > no` as an ordinal value is safe lacking context. For instance, if the question is "are you a criminal", then certainly "yes" has a distinct and comparable value to "no"; if the question is "do you like brussel sprouts with your meal", who is to say that one value is greater than another? The "unknown" might be "it depends", which might be interpreted as better than yes, because "yes" suggests sprouts+cereal is as good as sprouts+chicken. I suggest the best answer, lacking more context, is either **nominal** or just **it depends**.

Comment: @r2evans What part of "**But imagine that yes/no/unknown were the answers to a question about preference of object A vs. object B.**" makes you think this answer advocates a decision of 'ordinal' without any context?

Comment: I don't read anyone here as suggesting that unknown is safely taken as  intermediate between yes and no unless there is context that justifies such a tactic. .

Comment: I think most of this is saying basically the same thing: it _might_ be ordinal based on the question itself, we really don't know. @NickCox, `the point is that 'unknown' would be in the middle` is what I was going off of. Perhaps I'm just leaning a bit more towards saying "it depends", and it could go in either direction, varying per-question. (I think it's important (for me) to remember that ordinal does not have to mean increasing "goodness".) Sorry mkt, not an attack.

Comment: We agree then: at most mkt was saying that it might make sense.

Comment: @r2evans No worries, and I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: I realize here we are considering three elements, but I thought I would share a small mathematical fact that any binary relation (order or otherwise) on only two elements [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) satisfies being a [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation). And transitivity occurs in most, possibly all, notions of order that I have seen.

Answer (score 4):

Reading the very interesting discussion here, I'd like to make a rather philosophical point that may be controversial, but is in my view well illustrated by how the discussion goes.

The point is this. There is a decision to be made here on how to treat the "unknown" values, and whether the resulting variable is treated as nominal ("categorical") or ordinal. *This is a matter of judgment and not a matter of truth.* We just can't say "you have to do this or that".

Furthermore, this decision concerns the *meaning* of the response categories rather than the data, so in general it cannot be decided in a data based way. This however doesn't mean that the data cannot be used. For example, one could imagine that there are other variables in the study and one could see that the other variables are related to the variable in question (let's say V1) in such a way that values of the other variables for the cases where V1=unknown tend to be in between the values for V1=yes and V1=no. This would constitute some evidence that "unknown" is located between yes and no, even though the evidence wouldn't be conclusive (other variables might be related to V1 in a non-monotonic way).

The user may also be tempted to run different versions of further analyses treating "unknown" in different ways, and decide which of the outcomes "looks best"/most plausible. This is problematic, because it will induce a bias in the sense that the user influences the analysis in the direction of what they want to see. So I advise against it.

It however illustrates that the decision of how to deal with the variable will also need to take into account what analyses are later done with the variable, as it depends on the later analysis what the impact of the decision actually is. And in fact running different analyses using different potentially valid versions of the variable can be used in a better way as a means to *sensitivity analysis*; i.e., in order to explore how analysis results are affected by the decision. If results are pretty much the same, the good news is that they can be seen as unaffected by this decision. Note that multiple imputation techniques for missing values do something similar.

I'm saying that the decision is not about "finding out what the variable truly is" but rather about judgment. But of course arguments can be made. As mentioned in other answers, other than looking at the data, it is important to consider background knowledge and the meaning of measurements. There may be knowledge (question wording, context) that indeed would support seeing "unknown" as an intermediate option between "yes" and "no"; there may be knowledge that could suggest that "unknown" is essentially different from both of these and should actually be treated as a third nominal category (note that there may even be cultural changes over time regarding such judgments, e.g., gender questions), and it may be that the idea is that we have a missing value here that really should be "yes" or "no" and nothing else, but we don't know, in which case a multiple imputation technique for missing values may be most appropriate.

One could even imagine investigating this issue in particular by asking follow-up questions to respondents who said "unknown" regarding which of these seems to be best for describing where they stand (obviously one needs to think carefully about how to word this). I suspect that in many real situations there may be a mix, unfortunately, i.e., some people think yes or no but won't tell you, some are somewhere in between, and some would argue that the question doesn't apply to them or similar. (In fact one can also critically revise the question because there may be reasons such as misleading or imprecise wording so that it produced many "unknown"s.)

Keeping further in mind that statistical models are different from reality and whatever we do is a simplification, particularly when dealing with missing values, insisting on a certain "overperfectionism" is not helpful. So I'd consider it legitimate to treat the variable as ordinal with "unknown" between "yes" or "no" if there are fairly good arguments to believe that *many* of the respondents have treated it in this way, even though one can still argue that chances are there is a good number of further respondents for which something else applies. Of course there needs to be caution with any interpretation, and one can add sensitivity analysis and further research, but ultimately the issue with missing values always is that we can't really know what's behind them, and whatever we do might be seen as "wrong" with a different interpretation in mind. Ultimately it will not normally be identifiable from observations which way of treating them is "correct", so that the idea that there is a single "correct" treatment is in my view wrong. So I say, it's a matter of judgment. (Note that any multiple imputation mechanism will be based on a model that of course may be wrong, see also https://www.jstor.org/stable/20203830 .)

Regarding the distinction between nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio scales I'd like to say something similar to the problem of missing values imputation. This classical distinction has been often criticised, (a) regarding whether it "correctly" classifies all relevant types of measurement and (b) what are the implications of this, such as "don't compute means of ordinal variables". Much of this criticism is in my view justified if the classical scheme is taken as a general prescription. However, I also think that it is very useful and enlightening to at least start thinking about scale types in a systematic manner. Much better and thoughtful analyses will happen if people have in mind that scale types are something to be considered, even though they may at some point disagree with certain "general recipes" and do something different in their specific problem, hopefully for good reasons. This is in my view the "true value" of the scale types concept, not that it were "the generally correct way to classify scales". Similarly, there is no single correct way to deal with missing values, but it is much better to start thinking about these in terms such as "missing at random", or "can we interpret them as their own category or not, and if so is the resulting variable ordinal" than just mindlessly imputing them somehow or deleting missing cases.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting take on this:

If you encode "unknown" as some value between the level of "yes" and the level of "no" you are actually performing an imputation (a bad one, but an imputation nonetheless). The variable is still binary. If handling it categorically, then the missing data strategy is the use of a missingness indicator. Imputation is an analysis decision and doesn't affect the variable's nature. On the other hand, you often receive code books documenting the data and they might describe the variable as "variable: dietary restriction (binary): no=0, yes=1, unknown=-9" or something of the sort. Encoding is an analysis decision and doesn't affect the variable's nature.

I contend that nary an R or SAS user would disagree that the following list : {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NA, 0} or [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, ., 0] is consistent with a *binary* variable.

Comment: *Variable's nature* sounds like [level of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement). Are they synonyms in this case?

Comment: @Galen not really. Suppose for instance in my analysis, "unknown" is treated as missing, so I perform mean imputation. That is, if 30% of the sample reports "no" and has x=0, "unknowns" are imputed to 0.3. I actually can't claim no < unknown < yes because the value is unobserved, the imputation is purely pragmatic. I don't mean a "variable's nature" in any precise way except that the value of "unknown" reflects a limitation of my design rather than a tangible quantity.

Answer (score 1):

## Visualizations

mkt's answer is correct in my opinion, but I thought I would briefly illustrate some of the choices that are possible. Let us suppose that $\text{yes} \geq \text{no}$, leaving what to decide about $\text{unknown}$.

$\text{unknown}$ can be connected to $\text{yes}$, or not, and connected to $\text{no}$, or not. This might make it seem like there are four options, but we should also consider the order of pairs. That is $\text{yes} \geq \text{unknown}$ is not in general the same thing as $\text{yes} \leq \text{unknown}$, and likewise for the pairings with $\text{no}$.

First option is that unknown is greater than both, which is fine as a partial order.

[image]

Another option is this cycle, which cannot be a partial order (although it can be a "cyclic total order" if you allow that notion):

[image]

Next option is that unknown is less than yes but greater than no, which is a valid partial order.

[image]

And the last option is that unknown is less than both, which is also a valid partial order.

[image]

Here is the code I used to generate the strings which I threw into the [mermaid live editor](https://mermaid.live/) (I was in too much of a hurry to write code to plot the network diagrams nicely):

```py
from itertools import product

no = [
    ('unknown', 'no'),
    ('no', 'unknown')
    ]

yes = [
    ('unknown', 'yes'),
    ('yes', 'unknown')
    ]

default = (('yes', 'no'),)

relations = [r  + default for r in product(yes, no)]

for j, relation in enumerate(relations):
    print(f'relation {j}')
    mermaid_string = '\n'.join([' --> '.join(i) for i in relation])
    print(mermaid_string, '\n')
```

I left out some cases where the graph is not fully connected (in a weak sense). In those cases we don't have a partial order because the transitivity property (of a partial order) will not hold. I left the cycle in b/c of laziness/expedience. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

## Ordinal Regression (And Rank-Based Statistics For That Matter)

While it wasn't my original goal in this post, some may wonder how this get's us back to doing things like ordinal regression. One straightforward approach is to [grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) the partial order. That effectively gives us a sort of rank even if we started with elements of a set that were not objects normally thought of as having numbers. Order is about how things pair together, and for ordinal regression you can actually skip grading the elements and compute the eCDF cumulatively in topological order of the graph.

## Quick Hack To Check Pairs For Partial Order

While I didn't use it here, you can think of a partial order in a rather indirect way which happens to be handy for checking if collection of pairs form a partial order. You can think of a partial order as the edge set of a directed acyclic graph that is equal to its own transitive closure.

So with a tool like Networkx, you can use these checks on a `nx.DiGraph` object instance `d`:

- [`nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(d)`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.is_directed_acyclic_graph.html)
- [`nx.transitive_closure_dag(d) == d`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.transitive_closure_dag.html)

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605349/what-is-a-rank

Answer (score 1):

If these are three levels of the actual measurement, it may be ordinal, and may be possible to do correlation and regression treating these as -1, 0, 1 (do you like sweets - no, do not know what to say, yes).

But if "unknown" is the state of genuinely missing data, this depends on the proportion between "yes" and "no" cases. If the actual data set seems strongly biased to one of the sides (say only 0.05 % respond "yes") yet 30 % of data is missing, assuming "unknown" as "half yes, half no" may produce the wrong bias towards the "yes" case.